# Slicing a string scanned from a bar-code into 2 input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

> The HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <label class="sr-only" for="product">Product</label>
    <input id="product" type="text" placeholder="Product" maxlength="7" autofocus>

    <label class="sr-only" for="batch">Batch</label>
    <input id="batch" type="text" placeholder="Batch" maxlength="5">
</div>
```

> The jQuery looks like this:

```
 $('#product').on('keyup', function() {
    let product = $(this).val().slice(0, 7);
    let batch =  $(this).val().slice(9, 14);
    if ($(this).val() && $(this).val().length === 7) {
        $(this).val(product);
        $(this).next().focus().val(batch);
    }
});
```

When I'm scanning the barcode, it reads this string `WXYZ519 -8012456789`.

I need to slice this string so that the `input` with `id="product"` and `id="batch"` gets the values as `WXYZ519` and `80124` respectively without the hyphen and space in between.

The first input does receive the right value but I just couldn't get the second input to slice the right value into it.

Can anyone tell me why and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hyc6sdub/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your range appears to be wrong if you wanted to get the entire 2nd half of the string.

If you change

```
$(this).val().slice(9, 14);
```

to

```
$(this).val().slice(9, $(this).val().length);
```

it will contain a string that starts at 9 and ends at the end of the string.

---

Another alternative which I believe is much cleaner and less error prone would be this:

```
let split = $(this).val().split(" -");
let product = split[0];
let batch =  split[1];
```

Comment: hi, sorry if i did not explicitly mention the 2nd half of the string, but i did write i need the value to be as stated in my question, so yeah, i'm actually not wanting to slice till the end